# Как узнать какой фрагмент запущен?

Tags: android

Ребята, мне нужно узнать какой фрагмент в данный момент запущен.
Как это сделать?
Я хочу сделать так, чтобы при определённом открытом фрагменте в активити не выводились уведомления. Для этого мне нужно как-то узнать, какой в данный момент запущен фрагмент.

Comment: Вы как то смутно описали вопрос, очень много есть способов, как определить какой фрагмент запущен и их реализация зависит напрямую от того, как вы показываете пользователю фрагменты. Но как самый вероятный ответ - используйте instanceOf, для сравнения фрагментов. А определить какой именно запущен - зависит исключительно от того как вы добавляете фрагмент на экран (FragmentPagerAdapter, supportfragment, xml)

Comment: в целом можно рекурсивно через Activity FragmentManager и ChildFragmentManager`ы, только возникает вопрос как выделить нужный, потому что на экране их может быть несколько

Comment: @Chaynik
                    Fragment fragment=new AddUser();
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame,fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();

Comment: Мне нужно как-то программно узнать какой Fragment запущен.
Пробовал getContext()=Chat.class,
что-то в таком варианте,но это не правильный вариант

Comment: Опять же при вашем варианте есть куча способов, как узнать какой фрагмент запущен) Но в любом случаем Вам придется добавить tag в replace, при наступлении нужного события используйте MyFragment myFragment = (MyFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("tag") и условие myFragment != null && myFragment.isVisible() - так вы узнаете запущен ли ненужный вам фрагмент или нет....

Comment: еще вариант использовать backStack http://stackoverflow.com/a/25547781/2667883

Comment: @Chaynik я сделал так как ты написал,но подчёркнуто красной линией
У меня есть фрагмент Chat.class. Вызываю я его в активити(у меня navigation bar).Я присвоил тег данному фрагменту "Chat". Как мне узнать сейчас запущен этот фрагмент или другой?

Comment: @Chaynik
Пробовал вот так:
                if(!getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Chat").isVisible()){
                    push();
                }

Comment: Для начала добавьте tag для добавляемого фрагмента.  fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame,fragme‌​nt, "Chat_tag").addToBackStack(n‌​ull).commit(); после чего вытащите в переменную фрагмента Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Chat_tag") убедитесь что фрагмент есть (fragment != null) и после этого проверьте на видимость (fragment.is‌​Visible())

Comment: @Chaynik помогло!!!

Comment: Создайте лучше класс, который будет следить за открытым фрагментом

Answer (score 4):

Универсального решения через систему нет:

- `FragmentManager` не предоставляет информации о текущем отображаемом фрагменте.
- Методы типа `isVisible()` не гарантируют верной информации если вы используете разные способы отображения фрагментов (например show/hide вместо replace)

Правильный способ - завести единый метод для отображения/смены фрагмента. В нём сохраняйте в специальную переменную какой именно фрагмент у вас сейчас отображается. По это переменной как раз и делайте нужные вещи.

Comment: использую только replace